# Как стоит подключать библиотеку three.js к своему файлу? Как стоит подключать конструкторы GLTFLoader и FontLoader?

Tags: javascript, html, импорт, three.js

я уже большое количество времени пытаюсь решить эту проблему, изучил множество материала, перечитал много ответов на стаке и окончательно запутался. У меня есть сайт, запускаемый на локальном сервере (Open Server), код я вставил в codepen - https://codepen.io/izura1419/pen/YzEzgxg .
Изначально сайт работал как нужно. на страницу загружалась 3Д модель и 3Д текст. Библиотеку и загрузчик GLTF  я загружал,  как обычный скрипт через ссылку в body
`<script src="three.min.js"></script>`

`<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js"></script>`

[image: так сайт выглядел изначально]

Затем я загрузил его на хост https://izura1419.github.io/my-vaporwave/ и через некоторое время пропала модель с данной ошибкой

```
TypeError: THREE.LoaderUtils.resolveURL is not a function
    at GLTFLoader.js:2379:36
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at GLTFParser.loadBuffer (GLTFLoader.js:2377:11)
    at GLTFParser.getDependency (GLTFLoader.js:2281:25)
    at GLTFParser.loadBufferView (GLTFLoader.js:2398:16)
    at GLTFLoader.js:2275:41
    at GLTFParser._invokeOne (GLTFLoader.js:2210:20)
    at GLTFParser.getDependency (GLTFLoader.js:2273:25)
    at GLTFParser.loadAccessor (GLTFLoader.js:2433:35)
    at GLTFParser.getDependency (GLTFLoader.js:2269:25)

THREE.GLTFLoader: Couldn't load texture textures/Stone_emissive.png
THREE.GLTFLoader: Couldn't load texture textures/Crown_baseColor.png
THREE.MeshStandardMaterial: 'format' is not a property of this material.
```

Я начал фиксить эту проблему и в конце концов пропал текст, но появилась модель.
Пытался добавлять библиотеку через модули, импортировать файлы
Код в codepen это то, как выглядит мой сайт на данный момент. В локальном сервере он выдаёт ошибку

```
        
       WARNING: Multiple instances of Three.js being imported.
three.min.js:6 
        
       THREE.TextGeometry has been moved to /examples/jsm/geometries/TextGeometry.js
```

А в codepen и вообще пишет, что не нашёл THREE.

Я борюсь с этим сайтом уже большое количество времени и, кажется, он начал побеждать. Без Вашей помощи, я, наверное, сойду с ума. Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте `import`, как в примерах:

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 ;

    overflow: hidden;

    cursor: pointer;  
}
canvas{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    display: block;
    background: url('https://cdnb.artstation.com/p/assets/images/images/018/861/861/large/finn-mccarthy-1000-samples-with-sun.jpg?1561007514');
    background-position: center top;
}
```

```html
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.136.0";
import { OrbitControls } from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.136.0/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls";
import { GLTFLoader } from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.136.0/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader";
import { FontLoader } from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.136.0/examples/jsm/loaders/FontLoader";
import { TextGeometry } from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.136.0/examples/jsm/geometries/TextGeometry";

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
  75,
  window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
  0.1,
  1000
);
camera.position.z = 20;
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true, alpha: true});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

//let controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight("blueviolet", 10);
light.position.set(-2, 0, 20);
scene.add(light);

//добавление музыки для атмосферности
const body = document.querySelector("body");
const audioMac = new Audio("macintosh-plus-420.mp3");

audioMac.volume = 0.1;

body.onclick = () => {
  audioMac.play();
  body.style.cursor = "default";
};
//загрузка модели и установление её настроек
const loader = new GLTFLoader();

loader.load(
  "https://threejs.org/examples/models/gltf/Nefertiti/Nefertiti.glb",
  function (gltf) {

    let model = gltf.scene;
    model.traverse(node => {
      if (node.isMesh){
        node.material.map = null;
        node.material.metalness = 0.5;
        node.material.roughness = 0.6;
      }
    })
    model.position.set(0, -2, 0);
    model.scale.setScalar(0.4);

    model.rotation.y = 1.5;
    model.rotation.x = 0.4;
    
    scene.add(gltf.scene);
  }
);
//загрузка текста и установление его настроек
const loaderText = new FontLoader();

loaderText.load("https://threejs.org/examples/fonts/helvetiker_regular.typeface.json", function (font) {
  const geometry = new TextGeometry("its all in your h e a d", {
    font: font,
    size: 0.2,
    height: 0.01,
    curveSegments: 10,
    bevelEnabled: true,
    bevelThickness: 0.01,
    bevelSize: 0.005,
    bevelSegments: 2
  });
  const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: "royalblue",
    shininess: 1
  });
  const textHate = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

  textHate.position.x = -1.25;
  textHate.position.z = 18;
  textHate.position.y = -0.1;
  scene.add(textHate);
});

renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
})

</script>
```

Результат примерно такой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое! Вы дали мне надежду идти вперёд. Может быть, мы сможем как-нибудь списаться, чтобы я отблагодарил Вас сникерсом например?

Comment: @Izura Заходите на форум: https://discourse.threejs.org/, или в дискорд: https://discord.gg/j5Jr9Sch - я и там, и там под тем же ником, что и здесь :)